# Unable to connect with azure blob storage with local hadoop

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, hdfs

While trying to connect the **local hadoop** with the **AZURE** **BLOB** storage (ie using the **blob storage as HDFS**)with
Hadoop Version - 2.7.1, It throws exception

Here i have successfully formed the local cluster by setting the property

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>wasb://account@storage.blob.core.windows.net</value>
</property>
```

and followed by its key value for blob storage in core-site.xml.

while listing the file or making **HDFS operations** to the blob storage,getting the follwing Exception as

```
 ls: No FileSystem for scheme: wasb
```

Anyone please guide me to resolve the above issue.

Comment: where is this config file?

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to add [hadoop-azure.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure/2.7.1) in the hadoop classpath.
2. Download [azure-storage-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) project and build it using maven then you will get azure-storage-3.0.0.jar. Add the built jar in hadoop classpath.

Now you can do all the operations. Refer [Azure Blob Storage](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: @Kumar: does this also work with Hadoop 2.6? or it should be 2.7?