# spark-shell error : No FileSystem for scheme: wasb

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, hdpi

We have HDInsight cluster in Azure running, but it doesn't allow to spin up edge/gateway node at the time of cluster creation. So I was creating this edge/gateway node by installing

```
echo 'deb http://private-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu14/2.x/updates/2.4.2.0 HDP main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/HDP.list
echo 'deb http://private-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20/repos/ubuntu14 HDP-UTILS main'  >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/HDP.list
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/azurecore/ trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-public-trusty.list
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys B9733A7A07513CAD
gpg -a --export 07513CAD | apt-key add -
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys B02C46DF417A0893
gpg -a --export 417A0893 | apt-key add -
apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
apt-get -y install hadoop hadoop-hdfs hadoop-yarn hadoop-mapreduce hadoop-client openssl libhdfs0 liblzo2-2 liblzo2-dev hadoop-lzo phoenix hive hive-hcatalog tez mysql-connector-java* oozie oozie-client sqoop flume flume-agent spark spark-python spark-worker spark-yarn-shuffle
```

Then I copied `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common/` `/usr/share/java/` `/usr/lib/hdinsight-datalake/` `/etc/spark/conf/` `/etc/hadoop/conf/`

But when I run `spark-shell` I get following error

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasb
```

Here is the full stack https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebb6c9d71865c9c8e125aadbbdd6a5bc

I am not sure which package/jar is missing here.

Anyone has any clue what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for a solution to similar issues. Possible assist here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264020/unable-to-connect-with-azure-blob-storage-with-local-hadoop

Answer (score 8):

Another way of setting Azure Storage (wasb and wasbs files) in spark-shell is:

1. Copy azure-storage and hadoop-azure jars in the ./jars directory of spark installation.
2. Run the spark-shell with the parameters —jars [a comma separated list with routes to those jars] Example:

   ```
   $ bin/spark-shell --master "local[*]" --jars jars/hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar,jars/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar
   ```
3. Add the following lines to the Spark Context:

   ```
   sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
   sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.my_account.blob.core.windows.net", "my_key")
   ```
4. Run a simple query:

   ```
   sc.textFile("wasb://my_container@my_account_host/myfile.txt").count()
   ```
5. Enjoy :)

With this settings you could easily could setup a Spark application, passing the parameters to the 'hadoopConfiguration' on the current Spark Context

Comment: My bad. I have to stop using Mac Notes to save code snippets :)

Comment: Yep, much better now :) And a very good solution too, +1 from me.

Comment: `hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")` did not work in for me.(Spark 2.3.1, Hadoop 2.7.3). I had to set `hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")` instead. Now it's Ok.

Comment: @noleto Thank you for writing that comment!

Answer (score 1):

Hai Ning from Microsoft has written an excellent blog post on to setup wasb on an apache hadoop installation.

Here is the summary:

1. Add `hadoop-azure-*.jar` and `azure-storage-*.jar` to hadoop classpath

   1.1 Find the jars in your local installation. It's at /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client folder on HDInsight cluster.

   1.2 Update `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` variable at `hadoop-env.sh`. Use exact jar name as java classpath doesn't support partial wildcard.
2. Update core-site.xml

   ```
   <property>         
           <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.Impl</name>                           
           <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb</value> 
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>fs.azure.account.key.my_blob_account_name.blob.core.windows.net</name> 
           <value>my_blob_account_key</value> 
   </property>

   <!-- optionally set the default file system to a container --> 
   <property>
           <name>fs.defaultFS</name>          
           <value>wasb://my_container_name@my_blob_account_name.blob.core.windows.net</value>
   </property>
   ```

See exact steps here: 
https://github.com/hning86/articles/blob/master/hadoopAndWasb.md

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for specific use case I cant use client deployed through cluster deployment.